# tal nested dictionary syntax

Tags: python, html, chameleon, tal

Working with Pyramid, my code looks like this:

```
class PageData:
    @staticmethod
    def create_data():
        return [
            {   
                'key_1A': 'info1A',
                'key_2A': 'info2A',
                'nested_list_A': [
                    {'nested_key1A': 'nested_val1A'},
                    {'nested_key2A': 'nested_val2A'},
                ],
            },
            {   
                'key_1A': 'info1B',
                'key_2A': 'info2B',
                'nested_list_B': [
                    {'nested_key1B': 'nested_val1B'},
                    {'nested_key2A': 'nested_val2A'},
                ],
            },
            ]
```

And my html page code looks like this:

```
<span tal:condition="nested_key1A">     Open     </span>
<span tal:condition="not nested_key1A"> Closed   </span>
```

What is the proper syntax to reference nested_key? for a tal:condition statement?

Answer (score 0):

In trying to figure this out I found my answer...

> tal:repeat
>   Syntax: tal:repeat="name expression"
>
> Description:  Evaluates "expression", and if it is a sequence, repeats this tag and all children once for each item in the sequence.  **The "name" will be set to the value of the item in the current iteration, and is also the name of the repeat variable**.  The repeat variable is accessible using the TAL path: repeat/name and has the following properties:
>
> https://www.owlfish.com/software/simpleTAL/tal-guide.html

```
<div tal:repeat="a nest_list_A">
<div tal:repeat="b a.nest_list_A">
<span tal:condition="b.nested_key1A">
```

a becomes the assignment for nest_list_A eg
b becomes the assignment for a.nested_list_A which will then access they key

if there is a value for the key, then tal:condition will continue as normal, otherwise it will skip  while rendering.