# Pyramid / mongo : building a nested tal:repeat for a EmbeddedDocumentListField

Tags: python, mongodb, pyramid, chameleon

i'm building a little app and testing at the same time Pyramid/Chameleon + MongoDB
So far, I LOVE it but I've encountered a dead end

Quick look a the data I want to display from a category collection

```
_id:"category"
themes:Array
  0:Object
    _id:"theme1"
  1:Object
    _id:"theme2"
  2:Object
    _id:"theme3"
user:"username"
```

Themes are an EmbeddedDocumentListField in mongoengine (but for this I only need the id)

I worked out how to tal:repeat my categories with

*pt file*

```
<div class = "category" tal:repeat="c categories">
  <h2>${c.id}</h2>
</div>
```

*viewmodel*

```
self.categories = get_category_for_user(user)
```

What I want now is to nest tal:repeat to display a result like this

```
<div class = "category" tal:repeat="c categories">
  <h2>${c.id}</h2>
  <div class="theme" tal:repeat="t themes">
    <div class="title">
      <a href="/theme/${t.id}">${t.id}</a></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The thing is to get themes, i need the category, and I haven't figured how to extract the category used in the loop to the viewmodel. Is there any way to pass variables from the pt to the viewmodel py file? Something like *tal:repeat t themes(${c.id})* ?
Or am I doing this completly wrong and there is a simple way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my answer in a previous question here, sorry for disturbance

[tal nested dictionary syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45319983/tal-nested-dictionary-syntax)

The answer was VERY simple :

```
<div class = "category" tal:repeat="c categories">
  <h2>${c.id}</h2>
  <div class="theme" tal:repeat="t c.themes">
    <div class="title">
      <a href="/theme/${t.id}">${t.id}</a></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Diffence lies on line 3 with reuse of the c variable to get the nested data.

Pyramid is awesome.